# Check excel cell if font is a certain color?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I want to use vba to check if the text in a cell in excel is of a certain color, lets say red. Any ideas?

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24132665/return-rgb-values-from-range-interior-color-or-any-other-color-property

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### I want to use VBA to check if the text in a cell in excel is of a certain color

> lets say red

You can use `Font.ColorIndex`

See below for an example.

To retrieve the cell colour use:

```
=GetFontColor(A1)
```

---

#### VBA – Get font color Function

> When we have colors on our sheets data and want, for instance, to
>   count how many “red” words we have on our sheet, that is not possible
>   because there is no formula in Excel to check for font colors. Instead
>   we can create our own VBA Function to get the font color. It’s a very
>   simple code. You have to insert it on a VBA module on your sheet.
>
> ```
> Function GetFontColor(ByVal Target As Range) As Integer
>     GetFontColor = Target.Font.ColorIndex
> End Function
> ```
>
> Then you can use it on your sheet like this:
>
> ```
> =GetFontColor(A2)
> ```
>
> Below is an example on how you can use this function. In column C we
>   put the font color of text in column A.
>
> [image: alt]
>
> To count the number of “red” words in column A we can use:
>
> ```
> COUNTIF(C2:C9,3)
> ```
>
> The `3` in the formula refers to the color red.

Source [VBA – Get font color Function](http://www.excel-user.com/2009/11/vba-get-font-color-function.html). Script has been tweaked to match the requirements of the question.

---

#### What if I want the cell colour?

Use the following function:

```
Function GetCellColor(ByVal Target As Range) As Integer
    GetCellColor = Target.Interior.ColorIndex
End Function
```

To retrieve the cell colour use:

```
=GetCellColor(A1)
```

Source [Sum Cells based on Background Color](http://www.exceltrick.com/how_to/sum-cells-based-on-background-color/). Script has been tweaked to match the requirements of the question.

---

#### Further Reading

- [Color Palette and the 56 Excel ColorIndex Colors](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm)

Comment: Is it possible to only extract in a cell the characters that are formatted in one color?

Comment: Is there any way to extract all the colors in a cell if there are multiple font colors?